# Python 3.4 compatibility with numpy, scipy, and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am very new to Python and am wondering what versions of numpy/scipy/matplotlib are compatible with different versions of Python--or to what degree it matters that they match up.

Right now I am using Python 3.4.3, numpy 1.8.2, scipy 0.13.3 and matplotlib 1.3.1. I saw on the [scipy FAQ](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#do-numpy-and-scipy-support-python-3-x) that "the first release of NumPy to support Python 3 was NumPy 1.5.0. Python 3 support in SciPy starts with version 0.9.0." But how should one know what versions of these modules are appropriate for python 3.4? Eg. I know that there is a scipy0.18, but will it potentially cause problems if attempt to use with python 3.4 and not 3.5? Sorry if this is a silly question, I just want to avoid having to uninstall/update different versions multiple times, which I already have done.

Comment: when you try to install these packages they have the requirements check in place so they update if the versions are not compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a closer look at the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) installation.

You will install all needed packages in one step and beside that all the packages will be mutually compatible and **tested**.

If you need packages that aren't included, you can simply install them using internal packaging tool - conda:

```
conda install package_name
```

Comment: Remember that `pip install package_name` is also a thing, and is the built in way of doing this. Although this doesn't work for scipy on windows, where you're better to install via `pip install downloaded-file.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy. This still does all the dependency checking you'll need

Comment: Does `pip install package_name` (I'm on ubuntu) do dependency checking too then?

Comment: @uncreative, yes, it should do all dependency checks.

Answer (score 1):

Current versions, numpy 0.11.0 and scipy 0.17.1, should be perfectly fine with python 3.4 and 3.5.

To a first approximation, any non-ancient version of numpy or scipy is going to be OK with python 3.4.

It's good idea anyway to run self-tests after installation: 
`>>> from numpy import test; test()` and `>>> from scipy import test; test()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the very same page:

> NumPy and SciPy support the Python 2.x series, (versions 2.6 and 2.7), as well as **Python 3.2** and newer

Python versions in the 3.x line should all be backwards compatible anyway.