# Documenting that a script works with python2 and python3 and a particular matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, versioning, assert

**Greetings Stack Overflow!**

I work in a research environment in which I might be using 10 different computers with different versions of Python and/or matplotlib, numpy, etc.
It's all Linux, but some folks might use my code on Windows, which probably adds more complexity.

Many of my python scripts work on both py2.x and py3.x-- and that may be a goal, but I have legacy 2.X code that won't get ported any time soon.  **I would like a way to indicate whether the code has been tested on Python2 and Python3, or to assert that the code only works on Python2** (or with certain matplotlibs).

I could do this:

```
assert(float(sys.version[0:3])<=2.8)
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> assert(float(mpl.__version__[0:3])>=2.3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError
```

I have poked around on this site and found this related post
[(Checking python compatability with numpy and matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026670/python-3-4-compatibility-with-numpy-scipy-and-matplotlib)
The fellow in the reference post was just told not to worry.  "Python3.4 just works with matplotlib". I realize Anaconda is supposed to help with these sorts of problems -- and I am using it.  I come from an earlier age when mostly multiple code bases did NOT just work.

**Recommended approaches are welcome.  Do you like assert?  Is there a better
tool or technique?**

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` would throw an error if it does not fit, and render your code unusable with versions you did not test, even if it could have worked. If you code doesn't do anything bad to the computer (e.g. wipe disks, corrupt files) or the system if it fails to run correctly, which it probably doesn't, seeing that you work in a research environment, then you should let it run. If it encounters an error, then it stops. If it doesn't, it runs on. However, you should include a docstring at the head of your file with your tested versions in it, like this,

```
"""
Tested with
python <= 2.8,
matplotlib >= 2.3
...
... rest of docstring ...
"""
... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: Good point, DarthCadeus.  Adding the compatability info to the doc string sounds appropriate.  I was so hung up on **assert**, I forgot about **warn**.  In fact, quoting the documation on **warn**    * Warning messages are typically issued in situations where it is useful to alert the user of some condition in a program, where that condition (normally) doesn’t warrant raising an exception and terminating the program. For example, one might want to issue a * **warning when a program uses an obsolete module**